# Import python code in android project

Tags: android, python, apk, adb

I have a monitoring application that can be used to monitor devices using android. I currently have the code in python that I run from windows via ADB and get the results on windows in a CSV file.

I would like to create an android project that would behave as described above (an APK, in Java on eclipse), so I can run it without using ADB.

Is there a possibility that I can include the existing python code and call the methods from the old code (after installing the apk on an android device)?

Despite my online research - I could not get appropriate results. Can someone help me out here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check SL4A and Py4A ?

http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/

You may check QPython too.